# How to sort by track ratings in Rhythmbox?

Tags: rhythmbox

In Banshee, we could sort the songs by star-rating by clicking on the interface itself. This way, I could transfer my starred songs easily onto the ipod and other disks.

In RB, how do I show rating on the interface, and then sort them thus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Overview

This answer assumes you are using Rhythmbox in either 11.10/12.04 or later.

#### Add the Rating to the main view

From the global menu (move you mouse to the top of the screen) - choose *Edit - Preferences* and tick the *Rating* check-box

[image]

#### Now sort...

[image]

Click the new Rating field as shown to sort either *ascending* or *descending* depending on the number of ratings you have.

Comment: This works @fossfreedom, aplausos!